# unable to update values using shared preferences

Tags: android, retrofit, sharedpreferences

I am unable to to show updated values in edit text. I have database on server. I am updating user values using retrofit. On server values updates successfully but when i revisit the profile page it shows the values populated from shared preferences. On login i save values in shared preferences and throughout application uses these values.
The code for saving and retrieving the values is below:

Get and set email address in shared preferences

```
public void putEmail(String loginorout) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = app_prefs.edit();
        edit.putString(EMAIL, loginorout);
        edit.apply();
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return app_prefs.getString(EMAIL, "");
    }
```

Retrieve values from shared preferences

```
accountETSU1.setText(preferenceHelper.getEmail());
```

Comment: The code in your question is correct; the problem is likely elsewhere.  Please provide a [mre] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's more simple if you create a object called PreferenceHelper, in that object you create a static string for the name of the email like:

```
final String emailUser = "emailUser";
```

With that string you create 2 functions one to write:

```
public void writeEmail(String : email, Context : context){
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString(emailUser, email);
    editor.commit();
}
```

The other one to get :

```
public String getEmail(Context : context){
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sharedPref.getString(emailUser, "");
    return email;
}
```

Then call the object in your activity

```
Context context = this@YourActivity;
accountETSU1.setText(PreferenceHelper.getEmail(context));
```

Comment: Preferences have been updates but when i revisit edit text activity it shows old values. How to refresh them

Comment: if you coming back to the activity from anouther one you need to change the text onResume of the activity